# How to access class private member in standard library algorithms? c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, std

How Can I get private or protected members in the standard library algorithms without destroying encapsulation?
Is it possible to use `friend classes` for getting private or protected members?
The code is shown below.

```
class Person
{
private:
    
    double score;
    std::string name;
public:
    Person(std::string name, double score)
    {
        this->score = score;
        this->name = name;
    }
    bool operator()(const Person& obj) const
    {
        return obj.score > 180;
    }
    bool operator <(const Person& obj) const
    {
        return name < obj.name;
    }

};


int main()
{
    std::vector<Person> person
    {
        Person("John",200),
        Person("Trump",204),
        Person("Biden",205),
        Person("Obama",170),
        Person("Sam",180)
    };

    std::string Fname = "Sam";
    auto res3 = find_if(person.begin(), person.end(), [&Fname](const Person &p) 
        {
            return p.name == Fname;
        });

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add a simple "getter" within your class definition:

```cpp
const std::string& getName() const { return name; }
```

Then later:

```cpp
return p.getName() == Fname;
```

For more complicated situations you could `friend` another class or function. You could also define `operator==` that compares that object to a string, which could be even easier, as then you can do `p == Fname`.